# Cakephp: Insert data into sequence table

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-model

**[Cakephp 2.5.4]**

I would like to insert a new entry into a table with only one primary auto-increment key.

I have 2 tables :

```
mytables (id[A_I],name,sequence_id)
sequences (id[A_I])
```

I trying to insert data into a transaction using "saveAssociated" function:

```
$data = array(
    'MyTable' => array(
        'name' => 'test'
    ),
    'Sequence' => array()
);
```

Then

```
$this->MyTable->saveAssociated($data);
```

Associations between `MyTable` and `Sequence` are well defined into each Model. By the way the transaction always rollback.

If I add a new field into `sequences` table it works..

- **How can I succeed this transaction keeping an unique field into
  `sequences` table**

Answer (score 0):

Do you wanna save a new record on a single field to succeed the transaction? If is this, you can use the method below:

```
$this->ModelName->id = $id;
$this->ModelName->saveField('field', 'new record');
```

Sorry if wasn't this.